# Inverse of the $y=x^x$ in implicit form?

Tags: inverse-function, implicit-function

I want to find the inverse of the function $y=x^x$ in implicit form and **not by using Lambert W function**. Can you tell me how to find it?

Thanks.

Comment: $y=x^x$ *is* an implicit form.

Comment: This is also literally what the Lambert function _does_. It's like asking for an inverse of $y = e^x$ without using $\log$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Can I write it as x=$y^y$ ?

Comment: No - if $y = x^x$, that _doesn't_ mean $x = y^y$. Indeed, if $x=2$, then $y=x^x = 2^2 = 4$. But $y^y = 4^4 = 256 \neq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambert $W$ function was precisely introduced to solve the equation

$$y=xe^x$$ and those that can reduce to that form, such as

$$\log y=\log x\,e^{\log x}.$$

That essentially means that there is no other way.